# Own double-tab templates in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2012

So there's a trick in Visual Studio, that when you type, for example 'for', and double-press the Tab key, Visual Studio will create

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {

        }
```

Is there any way to create my own templates? As I don't use LINQ I'd like to, when 'db.A_' is typed, to make

```
db.A_TableName.Where(k => k.Field == Value).Select(k =>
    new
    {
        Name = k.Field
    });
```

Comment: note that there's another good and fast feature to recover pieces of code. Just select some text then drag it to Toolbox (the one you use in Form's designer which is empty in code view). An item with your code will appear (you can rename it by right clicking on it) . If you double click the item the code will be added to cursor's position. The problem is you cannot parametrize the pasted code like snippets do. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably referring to [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28v=vs.80%29.aspx%20%22code%20snippets%22.). The docs explain how to create new snippets and [how to add them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ybhaktf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It might be easiest to create new ones based on existing snippets that can be found in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#` (depending on your VS version and OS).

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio has more default snippets which is in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio (#Version)\VC#\Snippets\1033

file path as a xml format.

Also we can add some more custom snippets to our local machine.This is machine specific.

[click here for dotnetperls documentation about snippets](http://www.dotnetperls.com/snippet)